# PC to Phone via batch file

Tags: android, batch-file, transfer, sendto

I would like to send a .mp3 file to my android phone from my pc through my home network, I can successfully do this with Asus's program 'remote go'.
To transfer a file with 'remote go' from pc you just right click file icon and use the SendTo, then pick your device.
My question, is their a way of doing this with a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

***FTP*** could work. The only hassle is you would need to also set up an FTP server on your phone (Which is not really a problem for me, I have an FTP server ready so I can transfer files without a USB connection) and an FTP client on the computer. There is a built in FTP client in CMD. You can use that to automate your operation.

It would probably be something like

```
ftp
open (Local IP to your phone's FTP server)
send (mp3 file)
! <--- this will cause the ftp console to exit and return to normal cmd.
```